# How to store private documents in Django on production?

Tags: django, amazon-s3

What is the typical scenario of storing private files in Django on production server?

I wanted to use the [django-storerages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package - S3 bucket, but unfortunately after integration it turned out that private files cannot be stored for more than a week.
(AWS_QUERYSTRING_EXPIRE - the given X-Amz-Expires must be less than 604800 seconds). But I need to store them for the user indefinitely.

How can such files be stored in a remote cloud?

Answer (score 1):

S3 won't delete the files, they'll still be in the bucket and available. You just need to resign them to give private access to the files.

botocore library can help you create signed s3 object requests.

Comment: But...Each Amazon S3 object has data, a key, and metadata. Object key (or key name) uniquely identifies the object in a bucket. Object metadata is a set of name-value pairs. You can set object metadata at the time you upload it. After you upload the object, you cannot modify object metadata. The only way to modify object metadata is to make a copy of the object and set the metadata.

Comment: Why do you need to update an objects metadata? Aren't you only interested in storing the files long term and providing them with a link to it if they request it in the future?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe that your path can indeed be realized. Are there any ready-made cases for this solution? I am sure this is not the first time this question has been asked.

Comment: I actually don't think it's a well solved problem. I'd say most people have public buckets and use security through obscurity (uuid folders and uuid file names) - which make fishing for records nearly impossible.

Comment: Very likely, you'd need to write a wrapper around your return serializers that requests a new signed value, and updates the record before returning it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, Mr. Trent. But I think that this approach is wrong, because the files are stored in the public domain anyway and can be indexed and analyzed.

Comment: S3 buckets don't have to be public, that's a design decision. Even public buckets can be configured to not be indexable you'll find